# Error while installing packages

Tags: 14.04

whenever i run this comand : sudo apt-get install

```
$ sudo apt-get install

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 244 not upgraded.

2 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u40~trusty~NoobsLab.com) ...

Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2015-04-28 12:10:32--  http  download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u40-b43/jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz

Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 125.56.222.17, 125.56.222.11

Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|125.56.222.17|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily

Location: https  edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u40-b43/jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]

--2015-04-28 12:10:32--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u40-b43/jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz

Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.57.214.140

Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.57.214.140|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]

--2015-04-28 12:10:33--  http  download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html

Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|125.56.222.17|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK


    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.

Removing outdated cached downloads...

sha256sum mismatch **jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz**

Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed


No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup 
error from a previous failure.

                                                                                                      dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java7-set-default:
 oracle-java7-set-default depends on oracle-java7-installer; however:

  Package oracle-java7-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 oracle-java7-set-default

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



i remove jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz from my /var/cache ... but still showing the same error .
Its still shows in /var/cache.
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Oracle java 7, try this:

```
sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

If you really want to install java, I suggest you install openjdk (which is an open, reference-implementation of oracle java and works better in linux) instead of oracle-java. Purge oracle java by `sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer` and use `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` for installing JRE or `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` for installing JDK.

Comment: Thanks Ron 
i tried this ... still same error!!

i think there must be some issue with dpkg .

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ron, it worked perfectly for me.

@SumitJhajharia - maybe try this command first:
sudo dpkg --configure -a